# Store youtube channel's views in a text file

Tags: python, input

I  need to store the count of a  youtube channel  view in a text file With date and time ..in python
I am doing something wrong in putting the data to the text file
the error i recieve is name error name result is not defined.
And below is the piece  of code 
Can some one help or guide .The one marked in italic syntax can be wrong ..I am new to python.
Below is the piece of code i have written.
Kindly help me put the date ,time and view count in a text file 
Thanks and regards
.

```
def channels_list_by_username(service, **kwargs):
    results = service.channels().list(**kwargs).execute()
    print('This channel\'s ID is %s. Its title is %s, and it has %s views.' %
       (results['items'][0]['id'],
        results['items'][0]['snippet']['title'],
        results['items'][0]['statistics']['viewCount']))

    ***mvar = (results['items'][0]['statistics']['viewCount'])***   
    f=open("guru99.txt", "a+")
    for i in range(2):
        f.write("Appended line %d\r\n" % (i+1))

channels_list_by_username(service, part='snippet,contentDetails,statistics', forUsername='testing')
```

Comment: some doubts .1  results = service.channels().list(
    **kwargs
  ).execute() I think results is a array . Can some one confirm. How do i put the array contents to a memory variable like mvar Thanks

Comment: Can you tell us the name of the library from which `service.channels()` is? The documentation should state what's the return value of this function. Otherwise you can just try to `print(results)` and see what it does.

Comment: I cannot see where you try to write your data to the file (only dummy data)... If this is the only issue, this would work like `f.write("View Count: %d" % myvar)`, but I assume you know this already?

Comment: I have now added the top header part of code its a google api ..for youtube

Comment: # Sample Python code for user authorization

import httplib2
import os
import sys

from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.errors import HttpError
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.tools import argparser, run_flow

 
CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = "client_secret.json"

Comment: These are actually google api  for youtube .. so no details are available ..I have just copied the full code but  still i am not able to solve it..

Answer (score 0):

list.count(result) returns the count of occurrences of your views captured in result

Comment: This is the message i recive after i do the change you mentionedC:\Python36-32>v

C:\Python36-32>python px.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "px.py", line 60, in <module>
    m = list.count(result)
NameError: name 'result' is not defined

C:\Python36-32>

Comment: In your code it is results and you are passing result.

Comment: Still same issue thanks C:\Python36-32>python px.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "px.py", line 60, in <module>
    m = list.count(results)
NameError: name 'results' is not defined

Comment: debug it as  results is not  having the list.

Comment: def channels_list_by_username(service, **kwargs):
  results = service.channels().list(
    **kwargs
  ).execute()

  print('This channel\'s ID is %s. Its title is %s, and it has %s views.' %
       (results['items'][0]['id'],
        results['items'][0]['snippet']['title'],
        results['items'][0]['statistics']['viewCount']))